# How do I create a query that caters for two different groups of data and produces a result that is dependent on the first set in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, count, group-by, union

I'm trying to count all instances where a group of data has one or more fail.

I'm also Finding it very difficult to build this question so I'm hoping that showing an example will do the trick in explaining what I'm trying to achieve.

Sample data:

```
INSERT INTO test.answers (id, result_id, fail_all, fail_group) VALUES
    (1,1,0,1),  (2,1,0,1),  (3,1,0,1),  (4,1,0,0),
    (5,2,1,0),  (6,2,0,0),  (7,2,1,0),  (8,2,1,0),  (9,2,1,0),
    (10,3,0,1), (11,3,1,1), (12,3,0,1), (13,3,0,1), (14,3,0,1),
    (15,4,0,0), (16,4,0,0), (17,4,0,1), (18,4,0,1), (19,4,0,0), (20,4,0,1),
    (21,5,1,0), (22,5,0,1), (23,5,1,1), (24,5,0,1), (25,5,1,0), (26,5,0,1);

INSERT INTO test.results (id,team_id) VALUES
    (1,1), (2,1), (3,1), (4,2), (5,2);
```

I then run the following query:

```
SELECT
    COUNT(IF(a.fail_all = 1,1,NULL)) AS count_fail_all,
    COUNT(IF(a.fail_group = 1,1,NULL)) AS count_fail_group,
    a.result_id
FROM test.answers AS a
GROUP BY a.result_id
```

Result:

```
count_fail_all, count_fail_group, result_id
0, 3, 1
4, 0, 2
1, 5, 3
0, 3, 4
3, 4, 5
```

I need to create a query that groups by team_id and counts how many fails there are per result. If a result has more than one fail, then that overall result is a fail. thereby if the count of results in the above query is 3 (example: first result) then it should only be counted as one. The fail_group can be ignored for now as I believe that the same solution for fail_all will work for fail_group.

The result I hope for is:

```
team_id, amount_of_fails, amount_of_fails_per_group
1, 2, 2
2, 1, 2
```

I hope someone might be able to help me create the query that I need? I'm not even sure how to start.
Let me know if there is anything that I can do to adjust the query as I know it's not very well asked?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you want that output. Maybe something like this:

```
SELECT
  r.team_id,
  SUM(IF(a.fail_all = 1,1,0)) AS amount_fail_all,
  SUM(IF(a.fail_group = 1,1,0)) AS amount_fail_group
 FROM answers AS a
 JOIN results AS r on r.id=a.result_id
 GROUP BY r.team_id
```

This will get you this output:

```
team_id  amount_fail_all  amount_fail_group
1        2                2
2        1                2
```

Comment: The results that I seem to get are 
team_id, amount_fail_all, amount_fail_group
(1, 5, 8), (2, 3, 7); 
My issue arises because: if I have more than one fail per result_id, It should be counted as one. for example, in answers, If I have (1,1,1,1),  (2,1,1,1),  (3,1,0,1), the number of fails for result_id 1 is 1. This is because a result can only fail once. A team has lots of results and results has lots of answers. A result can only have one fail. but a team can have multiple results so thereby have multiple fails. I'm hoping that I can show how many fails the team gets?
Thanks !!!